# Why do i get this error when trying to create a new table mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

So very new to sql,

I am trying to create a table and I can not find why the syntax i am using is not working

```
   CREATE TABLE customer (
    cust-id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  NOT NULL, 
    first-name VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    last-name VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL, 
    address VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    phone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY(cust-id)
  );
```

The error message I get is
`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  NOT NULL,
first-name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
last-name VA' at line 2`

Comment: that isn't a valid column name in that format

Comment: Column names can't contain hyphens. The `-` in standard SQL is used for subtraction. Use an underscore instead, or (better yet) just omit it entirely. `CustID` is a much better column name. (Techically, in the ludicrous form of SQL used by MySQL, you can escape the `-` in the column name by using backticks to surround it, but you're going to hate yourself every time you write a SQL statement if you do so. Better to use a better name, and alias the columns as needed for presentation with an `as` clause.)

Comment: @ Ken White: Thanks very informative :)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the - isn't allowed in that form and yoz are missing a comma before the primary key

Your create table can look like

```
   CREATE TABLE customer (
    `cust-id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT  NOT NULL, 
    `first-name` VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    `last-name` VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL, 
    address VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    phone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`cust-id`)
  );
```

Or  you use the classic __ for column names like **cust_id** and so on

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this :

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
cust_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  NOT NULL, 
first_name VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL, 
address VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
phone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(cust_id)
);
```